# Hello World from Windows - Errors in Visual Studio

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am having trouble running the code from [Hello World from Windows - ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello%20World).

I'm using **Visual Studio 2015** on Windows 7. I followed the step-by-step guide, but get the following errors when Building Solution **rosserial_hello_world.cpp**:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: rosserial_hello_world, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------  1>  rosserial_hello_world.cpp  1>rosserial_hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall WindowsSocket::WindowsSocket(void)" (??0WindowsSocket@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall ros::NodeHandle_<class WindowsSocket,25,25,512,512>::NodeHandle_<class WindowsSocket,25,25,512,512>(void)" (??0?$NodeHandle_@VWindowsSocket@@$0BJ@$0BJ@$0CAA@$0CAA@@ros@@QAE@XZ)  1>rosserial_hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall WindowsSocket::read(void)" (?read@WindowsSocket@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall ros::NodeHandle_<class WindowsSocket,25,25,512,512>::spinOnce(void)" (?spinOnce@?$NodeHandle_@VWindowsSocket@@$0BJ@$0BJ@$0CAA@$0CAA@@ros@@UAEHXZ)  1>rosserial_hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall WindowsSocket::write(unsigned char const *,int)" (?write@WindowsSocket@@QAEXPBEH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall ros::NodeHandle_<class WindowsSocket,25,25,512,512>::publish(int,class ros::Msg const *)" (?publish@?$NodeHandle_@VWindowsSocket@@$0BJ@$0BJ@$0CAA@$0CAA@@ros@@UAEHHPBVMsg@2@@Z)  1>rosserial_hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned long __thiscall WindowsSocket::time(void)" (?time@WindowsSocket@@QAEKXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ros::NodeHandle_<class WindowsSocket,25,25,512,512>::requestSyncTime(void)" (?requestSyncTime@?$NodeHandle_@VWindowsSocket@@$0BJ@$0BJ@$0CAA@$0CAA@@ros@@QAEXXZ)  1>rosserial_hello_world.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl ros::normalizeSecNSec(unsigned int &,unsigned int &)" (?normalizeSecNSec@ros@@YAXAAI0@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ros::NodeHandle_<class WindowsSocket,25,25,512,512>::setNow(class ros::Time &)" (?setNow@?$NodeHandle_@VWindowsSocket@@$0BJ@$0BJ@$0CAA@$0CAA@@ros@@QAEXAAVTime@2@@Z)  1>C:\Users\doullylogo\Desktop\rosserial_hello_world\Debug\rosserial_hello_world.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals  ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241447/hello-world-from-windows---errors-in-visual-studio/) by [doullylogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27490/doullylogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was ambiguity in **3.3 Add ros_lib to project**. I was mistaken by confusing '**project**' with '**project folder**'

It was suggested that I (in **Visual Studio 2015**):  right-click **Header Files**, **Add -> Existing Item...**,  and **Add all of the files in the ros_lib folder that aren't in subfolders to your project.**.

In other words: include the header files.

---

Originally posted by [doullylogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27490/doullylogo/) with karma: 38 on 2016-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1